# Do I really need a Windows system in order to maintain Chocolatey packages?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, chocolatey

As described in [this Q&A](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95504/how-to-remove-my-account-from-the-chocolatey-gallery) I do not have a Windows system anymore. Do I really need a Windows system in order to maintain Chocolatey packages?

**Concerns**

- Ketarin - will it run on Linux
- Powershell - could we run powershell on linux
- Testing - will the package be compatible with various windows systems, e.g. 7, 8, 10

**Attempts to answer the questions**

*Ketarin*

[This post](http://alternativeto.net/software/ketarin/?license=opensource&platform=linux) shows alternatives to ketarin on Linux, but I wonder whether it is possible to check the version of a certain package and updates it if newer when I see alternatives like Ubuntu update manager

*Powershell*

According to [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/05/05/powershell-dsc-for-linux-is-now-available/) it should be possible to run Powershell on Linux.

*Testing*

I could imagine that if powershell is able to run on Linux that a part of the testing could be done, but I wonder how to test the compatibilty? Spin up some windows boxes on Travis? Would that be possible, is that too cumbersome or do I need to pay money for the Windows licenses

Comment: "According to this post it should be possible to run Powershell on Linux" That's not what that article is saying.  'Powershell DSC for Linux' is not the same as 'running PowerShell on Linux'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a Windows system in order to maintain Chocolatey packages (although it helps).

#### Running Choco from Posix

you can build [choco for use on Posix systems (at least Linux and OS X)](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco#compiling--building-source). We run the builds through [Travis CI and Mono](https://travis-ci.org/chocolatey/choco). At some point we will migrate over to CoreCLR.

And you can maintain packages from there.

If you have an alternative to Ketarin, then you should be good to go if you can get something that runs the updates.

#### Maintain Packages with Vagrant Box

You can use the Chocolatey Test Environment as well to maintain packages - https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-test-environment.

You will see that it is doing similar to what the verifier does. Folks run that completely from Linux.